# Asp.net Calling view by rising event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using this class :

```
public class SteamGet
    {
        public delegate ActionResult ResultDone(List<Steam> List);
        public event ResultDone OnResultDone;

        public void Get()
        {
            Debug.Write("Result Received !");
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                string data = client.DownloadString("http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001/");
                JObject steamobject = JObject.Parse(data);
                var rslt = steamobject.SelectToken("applist").SelectToken("apps");
                var objd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectResult>(rslt.ToString());
                OnResultDone(objd.MyList);
            }
        }


    }
```

And my home controller looks like this :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    protected SteamGet Getter = new SteamGet();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Getter.OnResultDone += Getter_OnResultDone;
        Task.Run(() => Getter.Get());
        return View();
    }

    private ActionResult Getter_OnResultDone(List<Models.Steam> List)
    {

        return View("ViewTest",List);
    }
}
```

so as you can see i'm calling the Get() Method then Returning the View , when the Event OnresultDone Raised i want to Call another View or refreshing the home view

my home view :

```
@using TemplateAspTest.Repository
@model List<TemplateAspTest.Models.Steam>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Main.cshtml";
}

<section id="intro" class="main">
    <span class="icon fa-diamond major"></span>
    <h2>Test one section ! </h2>
    <p>
        test done !
    </p>
    <ul class="actions">
        @{ 
            if (@Model == null)
            {
                <li>waiting ....</li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li>ViewBag.Message;</li>
                @Model[0].Name;
            }
        }
    </ul>
</section>
```

EDIT : 
i'am Returning View and waiting for a event to be raised i want to call another view when the even is raised

Comment: Please edit the question and explain more clearly what you are trying to do, what is the problem, are the errors, what doesn't work etc. Now it is a bit unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I edited it sir !

Comment: This isn't really how MVC (or any Web technology, except maybe SignalR) works.... You could show one view then do an AJAX call to the other that does the long running task?

Comment: The first problem you have (I believe) is that your controller is destroyed at the end of the request. So when you hit    return View(); } the controllers lifecycle is done..

I would add in an async method and poll it via Ajax. That should keep the controller alive until the job is done, and then you can direct to a new page, or return a partial containing the information to the browser